# BSOD when setting up OpenCV

Tags: opencv, bsod

I am trying to set up OpenCV on my Asus B53F Notebook (64bit Win7 Pro) and am getting a BSOD. I followed to following procedure:

1. Downloaded OpenCV 2-4-8.exe
2. Extracted the files to C:
3. Added ;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin  to the Path system variable.

The BSOD appears at random after that some times while launching NetBeans and others after closing the system variables dialog. I have already tried re installing the graphics driver to no avail.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Almost certainly has nothing to do with OpenCV itself, and something to do with your laptop drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformat your machine :/

This might (definetly) not be the thing you want to hear, but we (probably) won't be able to help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some hardware fault (Run a memory check). Definitely in no way related to OpenCV.